# Nested Platform.runLater calls vs sequential: When is it safe to read side effects of layout that happened on the JavaFX Application thread?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Because some Nodes do not have correct bounds until after a layout cycle, I have to do some relative positioning in a Platform.runLater call. Perhaps I need to convert these operations to use bindings, but that is not the question. This question is about how the JavaFX Application thread balances layout tasks with tasks submitted with runLater.

nested:

```
Platform.runLater( () -> {
  nodeA.setLayoutX( offset + nodeB.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() );
  Platform.runLater( op2 );
});
```

sequential:

```
Platform.runLater( () -> {
  nodeA.setLayoutX( offset + nodeB.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() );
});
Platform.runLater( op2 );
```

I expect that setLayoutX internally calls [setNeedsLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#setNeedsLayout%28boolean%29). In both versions op2 obviously **runs after** the call to nodeA.setLayoutX. The difference is that in the nested version, op2 is **registered after** the call to setLayoutX and in the sequential version, op2 is **registered before** the call to setLayoutX.

For both versions, the layout won't happen until after the first operation completes. The question is: for both versions, can it be determined whether op2 would run before or after the modifications to nodeA are processed by the JavaFX GUI thread? Is this behavior potentially platform specific?

To be less generic: Assume that when the JavaFX Application thread lays out the Scene nodeA is a part of, layout managers modify bounds. When op2 reads those bounds, will op2 see the side effects of the layout operation in A) only the nested case or B) both cases or C) not necessarily either case?

Answer (score 2):

`Platform.runLater` you can see like a queue, as long as the Application thread has not yet run. This means, that every call to `Platform.runLater` will place the `Runnable` in a queue, which is executed in that order.

For your example it does not make a difference, as `op2` is executed in the ApplicationThread always after `nodeA.setLayoutX( offset + nodeB.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() );`

The potential difference may be that in your nested case there are other operations in the queue between the `setLayoutX` and `op2`, because `op2` is added only after the `setLayoutX` operation has run.

Comment: I think you might be confused about when op2 is added to the queue. The sequential case adds op2 earlier than the nested case. The sequential case is more likely to have the two operations execute back to back. Neither case can guarantee back to back execution.

Comment: @TravisWellman: You are right, I mixed the two cases up. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You say that it does not matter, but the reason you give, that op2 is executed after setLayoutX, is already an assumption of the question. The question remains. When does the JavaFX Application thread lay out the GUI?

Comment: when there is an explicit requestLayout() call or when there is a top-down layout pass because a node is dirty, so it calls layout() and if there is a parent that parent will call layoutChildren() and it keeps going to it reaches the last leaf@TravisWellman, to some how answer your question your call setLayout() triggers updateBounds right which goes along to re-layout its children and get their bounds as well, so yes op2 will see the effects, but i am guessing the source of your problem has to do with the parent you are using.